# check_http with directory results in "Name or service not known"

Tags: nagios

I have a nagios system, working well and i wanted to check a specific url with check_http.
The command is defined:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_http_with_folder
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADRESS$ -u http://$HOSTADRESS$$ARG1$
}
```

and i call it correct ... But it throws me an

> "Name or service not known"

When i call it from my nagios machine from command line, it works well and i get an status result 200, so all okay.
The problem is now, that i want the nagios command working and not throwing an error.

Any Ideas?

P.S. The problem is only in the part with the -u xxx param, without it (in the normal check_http command without -u) it all works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled `$HOSTADDRESS$` in your command definition.  It needs 2 `D`'s.  Also, you might want to ensure there is a slash in between `$HOSTADDRESS$` and `$ARG1$` in the value you pass in to your `-u` command argument, or make sure that `$ARGS1$` has a preceding slash.

Comment: yes, thanks, it was just a typo in $hostaddress$, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Joe's observations...

Note the corrections:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_http_with_folder
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u $ARG1$
}
```

Then the `$HOSTADDRESS$` should be just that.  For example, `www.example.com`.  And `$ARG1$` should be the location at the host only.  For example, `/blog/index.php`.  The `check_http` check will build it into an actual `http` request.

Comment: thank you too for your answer, joe was just a little bit faster ;)